# browser compatibility

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typical pitfalls of cross-browser compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154132/typical-pitfalls-of-cross-browser-compatibility)

Generally what are the main issues of browser compatibility come when we create a web page?

Comment: There are a million different cross-browser issues that you could run into. Could you make your question more specific?

Comment: IE doing something different depending on what time of the day it is.

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154132/typical-pitfalls-of-cross-browser-compatibility

Answer (score 2):

There's a million different things, but [quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/) is pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

The main issuses can be divided into several categories.

#### Standards support

Each browser version supports a set of different standards up to a certain version, but there is usually some exceptions that are still not supported. A browser can for example support CSS up to version 2.1, except a few styles that are not supported.

#### Incorrect implementation

Although some standard is supported, it might not be correctly implemented. All browsers have had some problem like this from time to time, but Internet Explorer is known to have several well known problems that has survived more than one major version release.

#### Non-standard additions

Most browsers support some features that are not a standard yet, or simply an addition that will never be a standard. Notably Internet Explorer has plenty of non-standard features. A few of them has later been incorporated in a standard, but most of them will remain non-standard.

#### Variations within the standards

Although something is covered by a standard, it might not be strictly defined. Different browsers uses different solutions for what's not defined. How form fields look and act is one example of this. Although the basic operation is defined, they vary in function and appearence from browser to browser, and also depend on the operating system and it's settings.

#### System limitations

Different computers have different features available, which limits what a browser can do. The most common example is that different computers have different sets of fonts installed. Some fonts are almost always available, but which these are also varies depending on the operating system, so on any given system you can't be certain that any specific font exists.

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is entirely helpful but IE 6

In more seriousness, the more complex things you try to do the more issues you will have, the simpler you keep your CSS and such the fewer problems you will run into.

Comment: I disagree, this IS helpful. My experience shows me that in 99% of incompatibility cases the issue is IE vs. EVERY OTHER BROWSER.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main issue is related to the presentation of the web page. I tried to use CSS to give a style to the page but there were lots of problems to keep the page aligned between different browsers, and I tested only Internet Explorer, Firefox and Google Chrome.
This thing is more evident if you want to be compatible with older versions.